# Combining two big files from specific lines in Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have two large files that I want to combine in one file and gzip it as well. However for the second file I want to exclude the first two lines. How can I do it? What I have done so far is:

```py
awk 'FNR>2' /application/psmcHard_0.msOut.gz /JPT/psmcHard_0.msOut.gz > /all_data/psmcHard_0.msOut
```

Do you think this is the right way to do it? And how can I gzip the file?

Comment: once a fle is gziped, it is binary data, and `awk` can't handle binary data AND you can't count on any "lines" being found. You'll have to unzip your files and then run your awk script to remove the 2 lines. You can pipe the work like `{ cat firstfile.txt ; awk 'NR>2' secondFile ;} | gzip -c >fileout.gz` (or similar). Using a process grouping (with `{ ...}`, sends all output from the enclosed processes to the pipe, and ultimately to `gzip`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You input files are in compressed with '.gz' - awk will not be able to process them directly. You will have to unpack the files, concat them, and recompress the files

```
(
  # Pass first file as-is (no need to unzip/rezip)
  cat /application/psmcHard_0.msOut.gz
  # Unzip second file, filter required lines, and re-zip
  zcat /JPT/psmcHard_0.msOut.gz | awk 'FNR > 2' | gzip
) > /all_data/psmcHard_0.msOut.gz
```

Comment: Thank you. Can not up-vote the comment since I'm new to stackoverflow